# oracle sql grouping and custom ordering

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is source data

```
Due Date    Status       Activity Name               Completed_date
            Completed    Maintenance (ADV)              23-Feb-23
9-Apr-23    Assessment   Maintenance (ADV)  
            Completed    Records Management Standards   10-Mar-23
16-Apr-23   Pending      Records Management Standards   
16-Apr-23   Assessment   Records Management Standards   
10-Mar-23   Scheduled    Records Management Standards   
            Completed    Monitor Compliance             14-Feb-23
9-Apr-23    Assessment   Monitor Compliance
            Completed    Monitor Customer               23-Feb-23
9-Apr-23    Pending      Monitor Customer
```

And what i need is

```
Due Date    Status          Activity Name             Completed_date
9-Apr-23    Completed   Maintenance (ADV)             23-Feb-23
16-Apr-23   Completed   Records Management Standards  10-Mar-23
9-Apr-23    Completed   Monitor Compliance            14-Feb-23
9-Apr-23    Completed   Monitor Customer              23-Feb-23
```

I wrote 2 queries one to get the max of due date, completed date grouping them by activity name

```
select MAX(DUE_DATE) as due_date, ACTIVITY_NAME, MAX(COMPLETED_DATE) as completed_date from activity_history group by ARCM_ACTIVITY_NAME
```

And one more for custom sorting on the status column

```
select t.*
from (select R.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ACTIVITY_NAME
                                order by (case when status = 'Completed' then 1
                                               when status = 'Scheduled' then 3
                                               else 2
                                          end)) as rank
      from activity_history  R
     ) t
where rank = 1;
```

How do i merge this in to single query to get the above desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate and use `MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST...)`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(due_date) AS due_date,
       MAX(status) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY CASE status
                  WHEN 'Completed' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'Scheduled' THEN 3
                                   ELSE 2
                  END ASC,
                  COALESCE(due_date, completed_date) DESC
       ) AS status,
       activity_name,
       MAX(completed_date) AS completed_date
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY activity_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Due_Date, Status, Activity_Name, Completed_date) AS
SELECT NULL,              'Completed',  'Maintenance (ADV)',             DATE '2023-02-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-04-09', 'Assessment', 'Maintenance (ADV)',             NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,              'Completed',  'Records Management Standards',  DATE '2023-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-04-16', 'Pending',    'Records Management Standards',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-04-16', 'Assessment', 'Records Management Standards',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-03-10', 'Scheduled',  'Records Management Standards',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,              'Completed',  'Monitor Compliance',            DATE '2023-02-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-04-09', 'Assessment', 'Monitor Compliance',            NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,              'Completed',  'Monitor Customer',              DATE '2023-02-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-04-09', 'Pending',    'Monitor Customer',              NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DUE_DATE | STATUS | ACTIVITY_NAME | COMPLETED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-09 00:00:00 | Completed | Maintenance (ADV) | 2023-02-23 00:00:00 |
| 2023-04-09 00:00:00 | Completed | Monitor Compliance | 2023-02-14 00:00:00 |
| 2023-04-09 00:00:00 | Completed | Monitor Customer | 2023-02-23 00:00:00 |
| 2023-04-16 00:00:00 | Completed | Records Management Standards | 2023-04-10 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X_chEtor)

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` function (for `due_date`) in its analytic form.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From activity_history order by activity_name, due_date;

DUE_DATE   STATUS     ACTIVITY_NA COMPLETED
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
09.04.2023 assessment maintenance
           completed  maintenance 23.02.2023
09.04.2023 assessment monitor
           completed  monitor     14.02.2023
10.04.2023 scheduled  records
16.04.2023 assessment records
16.04.2023 pending    records
           completed  records     10.03.2023

8 rows selected.
```

Query (check line #3):

```
SQL> with temp as (
  2    select a.*,
  3      max(due_date) over (partition by activity_name) max_due_date,
  4      row_number() over (partition by a.activity_name
  5                         order by case when status = 'completed' then 1
  6                                       when status = 'scheduled' then 3
  7                                       else 2
  8                                  end
  9                        ) rn
 10    from activity_history a
 11  )
 12  select max_due_date, status, activity_name, completed
 13  from temp
 14  where rn = 1
 15  order by activity_name;

MAX_DUE_DA STATUS     ACTIVITY_NA COMPLETED
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
09.04.2023 completed  maintenance 23.02.2023
09.04.2023 completed  monitor     14.02.2023
16.04.2023 completed  records     10.03.2023

SQL>
```